# Find all ideals of the ring $M = \left\{ \left( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 2b & a \end{smallmatrix} \right) : a,b \in \Bbb{Q} \right\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let
$$
M=\left\{
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        2b & a
    \end{pmatrix}
 : a,b \in \Bbb{Q} \right\}.$$
We can show that $M$ is a ring. The problem is to find all ideals of $M$.

---

Here is my work so far.

In order for $I \subset M$ to be an ideal, it must first be a subgroup of $(M,+)$. But, I don't know how to find all subgroups of $M$, so I am stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

Your ring is commutative and generated by $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$, the latter of which behaves like $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore you have a ring epimorphism sending $1\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $x\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$ that makes a map $\mathbb Q[x]\to M$ with $x^2-2$ in the kernel.

This allows you to look at $M$ as an easily understood quotient of $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: "the latter of which behaves like $\sqrt{2}$ " i don't understand this statement. Sorry, this is the first time i have studied abstract algebra. Can you make it clear ?

Comment: @129492 I mean that if $A$ is that matrix, $A^2=2$ . Based on the observation, it suggests what the homomorphism should be. It is not a complex piece of reasoning, just an observation.

Comment: Sorry :( i still stuck with this exercises. Would you mind writing a full solution :(

Comment: Does it only have 1 ideal is M and {0} right ?

Comment: @129492 that is not one ideal, it is two.  The solution is almost complete already, especially with the other answers. What is unclear? Do you not know what the quotient looks like?

Comment: I finished this exercise by using defination of ideal and rings totally. It's different from the way you approach this problem. I haven't studied ring homomorphism so i don't know what we got after knowing what the quotient looks like.

Comment: @129492 OK: well I'm glad you found your solution. Still, I'd recommend working at understanding this too. It is a pretty standard way to think about it. Via the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems) my answer says the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$.  Then if you've covered basic factorization over fields, or the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) say, you'd know that $x^2-2$ is irreducible, so that the quotient is a field. Therefore: two ideals.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I will try my best to understand your solution <3

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the only ideal is $M$.

We denote as $(a,b)$ the elements of $M$. The properties of $M$ are that $(1,0)$ is the identity, and $(0,1)(a,b)=(2b,a)$, all elements of $M$ are linear combinations of these 2 elements. Also, $M$ is a commutative ring.

If $i \in I$ is invertible, then $\forall m \in M$, we have $ m . i^{-1} . i$ which implies that $I = M$ as soon as it contains an invertible element.

The only interesting elements of of $M$ that would participate to a non trivial ideal would necessarily be non invertible. Since $\Delta = a^2-2b^2$, this leaves 2 types of elements:
$$I_+ = \{(\sqrt{2} a, a \in Q)\}$$
$$I_- = \{(-\sqrt{2} a, a), a \in Q\}$$
As those elements are stable by multiplication $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and linear combination, those would be bona fide ideals.

The only problem is that $\sqrt{2}$ is a real number, not a rational, and therefore $I_-$ and $I_+$ are not part of $M$.

Comment: ...the only (nonzero) ideal is...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 2b & a\end{bmatrix}\ne0$; then
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 2b & a\end{bmatrix}=a^2-2b^2
$$
Can this be $0$?

Comment: it's impossible to be 0 cause we got  $a,b \neq 0, a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @129492 Indeed, so the matrix is invertible. This is not the full answer, though: one small step more is needed.